# preserving alias template instantiation info

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang

I am trying to write a C++11 library over [gcc vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), that clang also tries to be compatible with. So I started with some traits for the vector types:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N> struct vector_traits;

template <>
struct vector_traits<float, 3>
{
  static constexpr auto size = 3;

  using value_type = float;    
  using vector_type = value_type __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
};

template <>
struct vector_traits<float, 4>
{
  static constexpr auto size = 4;

  using value_type = float;    
  using vector_type = value_type __attribute__((vector_size(16)));
};
```

Note, how the 2 trait specializations are almost the same. Then I thought:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
using vector = typename vector_traits<T, N>::vector_type;
```

But alias templates can't be deduced. So, I can't deduce whether I've instantiated vector with `N`=3 or 4. Do any ways exist to preserve this information, without introducing a wrapper class/struct? Say

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct vector<T, N>
{
   typename vector_traits<T, N>::vector_type data_;
};
```

Comment: But you can still access the static `size` member to get `N`, what do you mean by "preserving the information" ?

Comment: The thing is that alias templates truly produce an alias, not a new type, and the vector type for N=3 and N=4 is the same. Their sizes are the same, as only power of 2 vector_sizes are allowed. I can't deduce `N` from `value_type __attribute__((vector_size(16)))`, it may be 3 or 4. The static `size` member would say 4, which may be wrong.

Comment: Can you give an example of something you'd like to work that doesn't?

Comment: @AlanStokes Since I can't deduce N, I do one MUL and ADD more than necessary when calculating the dot product, if N=3. Cross product is not defined for N=4, but I can't detect that.

Comment: It's still not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'd really like to avoid a wrapper class/struct with a lot of overridden operators. I distrust them performance-wise and it is such a small thing, deducing N.

Comment: Yes, you've stated what your goal is, but you've still not explained what your _problem_ is. BTW what is your concern regarding performance? And I don't think that this really counts as "deduction"...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Everything works, there are no problems in that regard, but I find the code ugly with a struct/class wrapper and possibly inefficient.

Comment: This is still not a question or a problem or anything that tells us what answer you're looking for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'll write an edit, with a possible answer, valid only for clang, later today, to clarify.

Comment: Why would a wrapper `struct` be inefficient (should all be optimised away anyway)? Moreover, that would be the only way to make your code portable, i.e. compiler independent. Note that those vectors are extensions (to the language), and hence the `operator+=` (say) may or may not be implicitly defined (it's up to the compiler), as this is outside of the standard.

Comment: @Walter There aren't that many C++ compilers out there and out of those, only 3 implement C++11 more or less entirely (icc, gcc, clang). All three implement the vector extensions. Portability is hence not a concern. As far as the wrapper being optimized away: you've answered yourself with "should". We don't know for sure.

Comment: *All three implement the vector extensions* yes, but not identically. Thus, for some of these compilers `operator+=` on vector types is implicitly defined, for others not ...

Comment: @Walter I'm too poor to be able to afford icc; with both gcc and clang I haven't encountered this issue yet.